# Laravel not passing values to form (only in production)

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have a registration form in my application. When I fill the values and submit the form everything is correctly stored at the db.

Now when I edit the registration i can see every value i filled in earlier, except the values I selected in a checkbox or dropdown. The strange thing in the local envoirment it works perfectly fine. But in production the checkbox and dropdown values don't display.

This is my Controller

```
public function edit(Registration $id)
{
  return view('registrations_edit', ['registration' => $id]);
}
```

And this is my view

```
<div class="form-group row">
    {!! Form::label('grund_beanstandung_kommentar', 'Grund Beanstandung Kommentar:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('grund_beanstandung_kommentar', $registration->grund_beanstandung_kommentar, ['class' => 'form-control col-md-7']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    {!! Form::label('sachschaeden', 'Sachschaeden:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3']) !!}
    <label class="radio-inline">{{ Form::radio('sachschaeden', 1, $registration->sachschaeden === 1 ? true : false ) }} Ja</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">{{ Form::radio('sachschaeden', 0, $registration->sachschaeden === 0 ? true : false ) }} Nein</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    {!! Form::label('praeparat_im_hause', 'Präparat im Hause:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3']) !!}
    <label class="radio-inline">{{ Form::radio('praeparat_im_hause', 1, $registration->praeparat_im_hause === 1 ? true : false ) }} Ja</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">{{ Form::radio('praeparat_im_hause', 0, $registration->praeparat_im_hause === 0 ? true : false ) }} Nein</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group row four-height">
    {!! Form::label('grund_beanstandung', 'Grund Beanstandung:', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3']) !!}
    <label class="inline">{{ Form::checkbox('grund_beanstandung_verpackung', 1, $registration->grund_beanstandung_verpackung === 1 ? true : false ) }} Verpackung beschädigt/verschmutzt</label><br/>
    <label class="inline">{{ Form::checkbox('grund_beanstandung_geruch', 1, $registration->grund_beanstandung_geruch === 1 ? true : false ) }} Geruch/Geschmack/Aussehen verändert</label><br/>
    <label class="inline">{{ Form::checkbox('grund_beanstandung_transportschaden', 1, $registration->grund_beanstandung_transportschaden === 1 ? true : false ) }} Transportschaden</label><br/>
    <label class="inline">{{ Form::checkbox('grund_beanstandung_anderes', 1, $registration->grund_beanstandung_anderes === 1 ? true : false ) }} Anderes (bitte angeben)</label><br/>
</div>
```

The textfield is getting the values from the controller, but the other 3 radio-buttons and dropdown-menus don't take the values from the controller.

Does anyone have a idea why that problem is happening?

Kind regards
Kevin

Comment: What happens on the live server if you use `==` instead of `===`?

Comment: @Taylor Foster Thank you dude that worked!!!!!! You saved my end of working day :D

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your deep equals `===` to double equals `==`. I get this kind of trouble all the time when I use `===` in my blade templates. The only thing I can contribute it to is that somehow our value is getting converted to a string and we are checking against an int., so since those two are not the same-of-type, we will get false back when checking a deep equals.